# Detecting VBA macro running from VSTO addin

Tags: c#, vba, excel, vsto

Is there any way I can capture if the change in workbook was done by user interface or VBA macro?

I have VSTO addin doing some stuff when user changes some cells in many files population. 
Some of the files have VBA macro in them and these macros can modify the same cells. I want to ignore this kind of action when the source of action is in VBA code.

My idea so far:
1) Events - did'n not find the right one
2) System Stack - have no idea how and for what I should looking for
3) Dynamic VBA code modification - adding flags - not elegant and not safe.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You cannot know if a cell was changed by a user or VBA code. If you want to ignore `Worksheet_Change` raised in response to VBA code, you will have to set `EnableEvents = False` before letting the macro run, but that alone can break the macro.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to detect who performs changes on the worksheet. If a Worksheet is hidden (see the [Visible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-visible-property-excel?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm174097)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396) property) and the Change event is fired then a VBA or VSTO code works.